# How can I perform a t test in R that tests the mean difference from a target ratio?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, ratio

In my data I have a ratio that aims to be 5:1. To test how close the mean difference is between the ratios in my data (of 10 items) and the ideal 5:1 ratio I carried out the following t test.

```
t.test(SratioA$ratio, c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), paired = TRUE)
t.test(SratioB$ratio, c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5), paired = TRUE)
```

Would a better test be:?

```
t.test(SratioA$ratio, c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5))
t.test(SratioB$ratio, c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5))
```

If not one of those how would I go about testing this?

Comment: Ratios do not follow a normal distribution. You can't use a t-test with them.

Answer (score 1):

You should really have posted also your data. Without them we cannot judge if the normality hypothesis needed for t-test is reasonable. But, however, the main problem with your approach have nothing to do with that, and would remain with a nonparametric test.

Let us first compare your two proposals:

```
> n <- 10
> set.seed(7*11*13)
> test.dat <- rnorm(n, 5, sd=1.5)
> t.test(test.dat, rep(5,n), paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  test.dat and rep(5, n)
t = -0.8295, df = 9, p-value = 0.4283
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.9087770  0.8845178
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
             -0.5121296 

> t.test(test.dat, rep(5,n), paired=FALSE)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  test.dat and rep(5, n)
t = -0.8295, df = 9, p-value = 0.4283
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.9087770  0.8845178
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
  4.48787   5.00000
```

They give the same result, why? Concentrate on the numerator of the t-stat (we will look at the denominator later). For the paired test we get
$$
   \text{mean}(x_1-5,x_2-5, \dotsc, x_n-5)=\text{mean}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)-5
$$
and for the nonpaired we get:
$$
\text{mean}(x_1,x_2, \dotsc, x_n)-\text{mean}(5, 5, \dotsc, 5)
$$
and this are equal. But, your error lies elsewhere, you do not really have two groups (whether paired or unpaired), you have **one** group, the 5's are not observations, they are specifying the hypothesis to test. By treating them as data, your variance estimate is in error. The way to do this is:

```
> t.test(test.dat, mu=5)

    One Sample t-test

data:  test.dat
t = -0.8295, df = 9, p-value = 0.4283
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 5
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.091223 5.884518
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  4.48787
```

(and then maybe replace the t test with some nonparametric test)